# Broadcast receiving error

Tags: android, android-broadcast

Scenario:

I am sending a broadcast from a fragment with the following code

```
Intent intent=new Intent();
                    intent.setAction("writeBalanceToNFCCard");
                    intent.putExtra("balance", Double.valueOf(result));
                    getActivity().sendBroadcast(intent);
```

And in the MainActivity, I am receiving that

```
private final BroadcastReceiver mReceiverWriteNFC=new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        double newBalance = intent.getDoubleExtra("balance", 0);

        write(newBalance);
    }
};
```

Inside the onCreate() of the MainActivity, I am registering that

```
 IntentFilter writeNFCFilter=new IntentFilter("writeBalanceToNFCCard");

   registerReceiver(mReceiverWriteNFC, writeNFCFilter);
```

Problem:
It works sometimes....an[image]d sometimes i get the following error

What am I doing wrong???

EDIT:
this is the write method

```
private void write(double newBalance) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Write to tag");

        //to display new balance on homefragment.
        SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
            editor.putString("newbalance",String.valueOf(newBalance));
            editor.commit();

            paymentData=new MyPaymentData();
        paymentData.setUid(operations.getUid());
        paymentData.setCurrency("dkk");
        paymentData.setAmount(newBalance);
        Log.d(TAG,"WRITE NFC: BALANCE="+ String.valueOf(newBalance));

        byte[] bytes = encodePayload(paymentData);
        byte[] encrypted = encrypt(bytes);

        new WriteTask().execute(encrypted,bytes);

}
```

EDIT 2:

After the error, see the following image, the write() method actually get called and does its function. The problem is customer will definitely not like to see an ugly app crash message..!!
[image]

Comment: What is line 450 of MainActivity?

Comment: post your write() method

Comment: line 450: paymentData.setUid(operations.getUid());

Comment: write() method added.

Comment: operations is probably null

Comment: Either `paymentData` or `operations` is `null`, or both :)

Comment: May be not....because when I see this error, it actually calls the write () method...and writes back. But other things stopped working and i see this ugly app crash popup

Answer (score 0):

You should register broadcast receivers in the onResume() method, not onCreate(). And unregister them in the onPause() method. I can't see your screenshot (blocked from my workplace) but even if this isn't the current problem, it will be aproblem very soon.

Move the register receiver code to onResume():

```
protected void onResume () {
    super.onResume();
    IntentFilter writeNFCFilter=new IntentFilter("writeBalanceToNFCCard");
    registerReceiver(mReceiverWriteNFC, writeNFCFilter);
}
```

onPause() should look like this:

```
protected void onPause () {
    unregisterReceiver(mReceiverWriteNFC);
    super.onPause();
}
```

Comment: it doesn't call the write() now

Comment: If you implemented this, I forgot the call to super.onResume() in th eonResume() method (see above, now fixed). Sorry!

Answer (score 0):

the problem seems in this line

```
paymentData.setUid(operations.getUid());
```

if so then the only reason is the `operations` is null. Please check if you initialized it properly.